# Pybind11 binding compilation fails - Static assertion fails with shared_ptr of Eigen::Matrix

Tags: python, c++, eigen, pybind11

I'm trying to compile [these Python bindings](https://github.com/AlejandroSilvestri/OpenVSLAM-Python-bindings) made for the open source project of OpenVSLAM/Stella_vslam.

As per the repository instructions, I execute the following command:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) -I/usr/local/include/openvslam/3rd/json/include -DUSE_DBOW2 /home/user/OpenVSLAM-Python-bindings/openvslam_bindings.cpp -o openvslam$(python3-config --extension-suffix) -lopenvslam
```

But the compilation fails with the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95USy.png):

```
In file included from /home/squiro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../attr.h:13,
                 from /home/squiro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/class.h:12,
                 from /home/squiro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:13,
                 from /home/squiro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/stl.h:12,
                 from /home/squiro/Desktop/OpenVSLAM-Python-bindings/openvslam_bindings.cpp:6:
/home/squiro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../cast.h: In instantiation of ‘struct pybind11::detail::copyable_holder_caster<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, std::shared_ptr<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> >, void>’:
/home/squiro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../cast.h:826:7:   required from ‘class pybind11::detail::type_caster<std::shared_ptr<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> >, void>’
/home/squiro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:242:63:   recursively required by substitution of ‘template<class Return> struct pybind11::detail::return_value_policy_override<Return, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<pybind11::detail::type_caster_generic, pybind11::detail::type_caster<typename pybind11::detail::intrinsic_type<T>::type> >::value, void>::type> [with Return = std::shared_ptr<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> >]’
/home/squiro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:242:63:   required from ‘void pybind11::cpp_function::initialize(Func&&, Return (*)(Args ...), const Extra& ...) [with Func = pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function(Return (Class::*)(Arg ...), const Extra& ...) [with Return = std::shared_ptr<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> >; Class = stella_vslam::system; Arg = {const cv::Mat&, double, const cv::Mat&}; Extra = {pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg_v}]::<lambda(stella_vslam::system*, const cv::Mat&, double, const cv::Mat&)>; Return = std::shared_ptr<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> >; Args = {stella_vslam::system*, const cv::Mat&, double, const cv::Mat&}; Extra = {pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg_v}]’
/home/squiro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:108:9:   required from ‘pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function(Return (Class::*)(Arg ...), const Extra& ...) [with Return = std::shared_ptr<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> >; Class = stella_vslam::system; Arg = {const cv::Mat&, double, const cv::Mat&}; Extra = {pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg_v}]’
/home/squiro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:1578:22:   required from ‘pybind11::class_<type_, options>& pybind11::class_<type_, options>::def(const char*, Func&&, const Extra& ...) [with Func = std::shared_ptr<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> > (stella_vslam::system::*)(const cv::Mat&, double, const cv::Mat&); Extra = {pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg_v}; type_ = stella_vslam::system; options = {}]’
/home/squiro/Desktop/OpenVSLAM-Python-bindings/openvslam_bindings.cpp:357:134:   required from here
/home/squiro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../cast.h:753:61: error: static assertion failed: Holder classes are only supported for custom types
  753 |     static_assert(std::is_base_of<base, type_caster<type>>::value,
      |                                                             ^~~~~
/home/squiro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../cast.h:1408:55: error: ‘pybind11::detail::enable_if_t<(! std::is_void<_Yp>::value), Return> pybind11::detail::argument_loader<Args>::call(Func&&) && [with Return = std::shared_ptr<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> >; Guard = pybind11::detail::void_type; Func = pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function(Return (Class::*)(Arg ...), const Extra& ...) [with Return = std::shared_ptr<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> >; Class = stella_vslam::system; Arg = {const cv::Mat&, double, const cv::Mat&}; Extra = {pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg_v}]::<lambda(stella_vslam::system*, const cv::Mat&, double, const cv::Mat&)>&; Args = {stella_vslam::system*, const cv::Mat&, double, const cv::Mat&}; pybind11::detail::enable_if_t<(! std::is_void<_Yp>::value), Return> = std::shared_ptr<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> >]’, declared using local type ‘pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function(Return (Class::*)(Arg ...), const Extra& ...) [with Return = std::shared_ptr<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4> >; Class = stella_vslam::system; Arg = {const cv::Mat&, double, const cv::Mat&}; Extra = {pybind11::name, pybind11::is_method, pybind11::sibling, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg, pybind11::arg_v}]::<lambda(stella_vslam::system*, const cv::Mat&, double, const cv::Mat&)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
 1408 |     enable_if_t<!std::is_void<Return>::value, Return> call(Func &&f) && {
      |                                                       ^~~~
```

This is what is defined in [line 356 of openvslam_bindings.cpp](https://github.com/AlejandroSilvestri/OpenVSLAM-Python-bindings/blob/main/openvslam_bindings.cpp#L356):

```
.def("feed_monocular_frame", &system::feed_monocular_frame, py::arg("img"), py::arg("timestamp"), py::arg("mask") = cv::Mat{})
```

And for more clarity, **feed_monocular_frame** is a function that returns a **std:shared_ptrEigen::Matrix4d**, as shown here in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBgi4.png).

I'm not familiar with Pybind11 in general, so despite I tried, I can't work out a solution for this problem. I've spent the last few days searching for answers, studying pybind's source code... but still can't wrap my mind around this.

For the record, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04; Pybind 2.9.2, and Eigen 3.3.0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Holder+classes+are+only+supported+for+custom+types

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks, but I didn't found an answer on those search results. In fact, there's only a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70933384/pybind11-return-a-shared-ptr-of-stdvector) wich has an answer there, and it doesn't apply to my question, because Pybind has eigen.h, which makes the conversion of Eigen matrices.

Comment: Well, then roll up your sleeves and extract a [mcve] from the code, so you can improve your question here. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself here, as I managed to make a solution after doing more research.

I found [a message on Gitter](https://gitter.im/pybind/Lobby?at=5c8fa32ed0133e21e5d4a74f) that closely related to the error. I'm quoting the user YannickJadoul:

> Don't return a std::shared_ptrEigen::ArrayXd, because pybind11 does
> not know what to do with it, because Eigen matrices get converted into
> np.ndarray and there's no way to hide the std::shared_ptr refcounting
> in there

This is what triggers the static assertion error when trying to build the bindings.

I found two ways to fix this:

1. Either modify the source code of the library and change the return type...
2. Or we can wrap the binding inside a lambda function that returns the matrix (and not a pointer to it).

I chose the second solution, as it doesn't involve modifying the library.

This was the original definition of the binding:

```
.def("feed_monocular_frame", &system::feed_monocular_frame, py::arg("img"), py::arg("timestamp"), py::arg("mask") = cv::Mat{})
```

And this is the modified version that fixed the issue:

```
.def("feed_monocular_frame", 
    [](stella_vslam::system &self, const cv::Mat &img, const double timestamp, const cv::Mat& mask = cv::Mat{}) { 
                    std::shared_ptr<Mat44_t> matrix = self.feed_monocular_frame(img, timestamp, mask); 
                    if (matrix)
                        return *matrix;
                    else 
                    {
                        Eigen::Matrix4d m(4,4);;
                        return m;
                    }
                }, 
                py::arg("img"), py::arg("timestamp"), py::arg("mask") = cv::Mat{})
```

Bear in mind that the null pointer check isn't relevant to this issue. You can return the matrix directly if you want (but if the pointer is null, you'll probably end in a segmentation fault, consider that!).