# C++ and pybind11: type_caster support for std::span?

Tags: c++, c++17, pybind11

I wish to pass a Python [numpy](https://numpy.org/) array to this C++ function:

```
int data(std::span<int> x) { return x.size(); }
```

Is it possible to write a [custom type caster](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/custom.html?highlight=type%20caster) for [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) that supports this signature?

pybind already has good support for `vector<int>`, but I would like to add support for a zero-copy version of vector, i.e. pass by reference.

It looks like there are some clues on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70933384/pybind11-return-a-shared-ptr-of-stdvector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two questions here, so I'll answer them each individually:

1. It is certainly possible to write a custom type caster for std::span -- my own implementation based off the pybind11 type caster for [abseil's span](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11_abseil/blob/33b5c7d4afbf31e9e5d6ade7fc78c5b1c6392461/pybind11_abseil/absl_casters.h#L317) can be found [here](https://github.com/robotpy/robotpy-wpiutil/blob/60de173ee925768ef33956a4933b2c6dbe921d45/wpiutil/src/type_casters/wpi_span_type_caster.h#L13). I haven't gotten around to submitting a patch upstream yet, but someone else is also interested in this (see [github discussion](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/discussions/4177)).
2. Most of the pybind11 STL type casters make copies of their sequences, so it's likely that any future std::span casters (like mine) are also going to make copies. That doesn't mean it's impossible -- the abseil span implementation does have a specialization where they would convert a span to a python buffer if it was a basic type.

Comment: Brilliant! Marked as answer.